# How to move databases to another drive in same server for sybase ASE 16 on windows.

Tags: sybase, sybase-ase, sybase-ase-15.7, sap-ase-16

I am trying to move sybase user database from one drive to another drive, can you please help me with procedure.

My database : Sybase ASE 16 
OS windows.

Comment: What have you tried do to so far? I mean, searching the web for `Sybase move database files` yields a number of results, the first several of which are from SyBooks Online. Have you looked at these, and had a problem finding what you need there?

Answer (score 1):

The officially supported method would be to use ASE's disk mirroring capabilities to move all devices.

- make sure ASE dataserver is configured for disk mirroring (`sp_configure 'disable disk mirror',0`); requires a dataserver restart
- run the `disk mirror` command for each device you want to move; once the initial copy has completed ...
- run the `disk unmirror` command to make the mirror devices the new primary devices
- when done, disable disk mirroring `sp_configure 'disable disk mirror',1`; there's a small performance hit for leaving this enabled when not needed; again, requires a dataserver restart

NOTE: If you move the `master` device, you'll need to update your startup script (and/or Windows service) to reference the new path for the `master` device.

---

There are some unsupported methods that consist of updating the `master..sysdevices` table and physically copying/moving the OS-level database files but ...

- you'll need to research those for yourself (see @RDFozz's comment)
- you'll need to accept full responsibility if you screw up and can no longer (re)start your dataserver